# Checking the state of a select control after the value has changed with a cookie?

Tags: jquery

I implemented some code (below) to check the state of ContentID and hide or show a DIV:

```
        <select id="ContentID" name="ContentID">
          <option selected="selected" value="00">Menu</option>
          <option value="01">Topic</option>
        </select>
        <input id="htmlEdit" type="checkbox" />

        $("#ContentID")
            .val($.cookie("ContentID_dropdown"))
            .change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "00")
                    $("#htmlSwitch").show();
                else
                    $("#htmlSwitch").hide();
                $.cookie("ContentID_dropdown", $(this).val(), { expires: 365, path: '/' });
                refreshGrid("Content");
            });
```

This code works BUT only when the value of ContentID changes. What I need is something that will also check the value after the value has been changed with a cookie.

The code in the change function that checks .val() does not check anything or run when the initial value is set with a cookie. So if my cookie is for example set to Topic then it is ignored and the htmlSwitch DIV appears when it should not. Is there a way that I could make it check the initial value and also hide or show the htmlSwitch id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you triggered it immediately after the `change` is bound?

```
$("#ContentID")
        .val($.cookie("ContentID_dropdown"))
        .change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "00")
                $("#htmlSwitch").show();
            else
                $("#htmlSwitch").hide();
            $.cookie("ContentID_dropdown", $(this).val(), { expires: 365, path: '/' });
            refreshGrid("Content");
        })
        .trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks - This seems to do the trick. I never thought about doing it the way you suggested. Your way is very clean. One thing I do notice is that for a second the DIV appears and then is hidden. Is there a way that I can make this <div id="htmlSwitch"> not visible by default and then have my code change the invisible to show() or hide()?

Comment: To lend further credit, this (well, the `change()` method directly) is used in the jQuery docs for `change()` - http://api.jquery.com/change/ (first example) - To answer your other question, @Jessica, simply use CSS to `display: none` your htmlSwitch element.

Comment: @Jessica sure, add the `hidden` attribute to the element: `<div id="htmlSwitch" hidden>...</div>`

Comment: @Eli - You sure? [WhatWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) warns against using that attribute in this way.

Comment: I am guessing by the name of the element that @Jessica is not hiding an element that contains content, but if I am incorrect, then you would be correct. You don't want to hide elements using hidden OR display: none because screen readers can't access the content. Other techniques would be preferable.